# Adjective or adverb

Tags: grammar

Is "far" an adjective or adverb in the following sentence:

How **far** is Los Angeles from New York City?

Comment: [General reference](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/far). Simply put, if you can use *the* (the far corner, the far Right) it's an adjective; otherwise it's an adverb.

Answer (score 1):

It is an adjective. Far describes the distance between Los Angeles and New York.

Answer (score 0):

Here, *far from* is a [compound preposition](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=5W6lWXl6ejkC&pg=PA113&lpg=PA113&dq=%22how+near%22+preposition&source=bl&ots=fEFlr_ukQ5&sig=cBxbXAf8W4JBb5R3z3KGcP8aHSY&hl=en&sa=X&ei=tAp6UqmjM8je7Ab84oHABQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22how%20near%22%20preposition&f=false)

> (LA is far from / near to / near NYC/SF.)

This is disguised by the separable construction:

> How far from LA is NYC?
>
> How far is LA from NYC?

cf

> How close to / near LA is SF?

Comment: I don't think it is that here, because on that analysis _how_ would modify the compound preposition, which seems anomalous. The reference you gave does not seem to consider _how far_ (though it uses _how near_ in a section heading), and is any case a text about semantics not syntax.

Comment: Alternative analyses become difficult when one considers say:  -Do you live near the school? -How near the school? --Do you live far from the school? -How far from the school? 'Near' would be a very anomalous adjective in the second sentence (How friendly the school do you find?)! So, with apologies to Yoda, I'll stick with the lesser anomaly: the prepositions 'near', 'far from' etc can be premodified by 'how' (and 'very') (cf just inside the kitchen). 'Near' etc even grade!: -I live nearer / further [away] from the school.